# generate rsa key valid for dkim validation

Tags: go, dns, dkim

I am tring to generate dkim key using golang, my current code is :

```
package appdkim

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/asn1"
    "encoding/pem"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func Keymaker(path string) {
    reader := rand.Reader
    bitSize := 2048

    key, err := rsa.GenerateKey(reader, bitSize)
    checkError(err)

    publicKey := key.PublicKey

    savePEMKey(path+".priv", key)

    savePublicPEMKey2(path+".pub", publicKey)

    return
}

func savePEMKey(fileName string, key *rsa.PrivateKey) {
    outFile, err := os.Create(fileName)
    checkError(err)
    defer outFile.Close()

    var privateKey = &pem.Block{
        Type:  "PRIVATE KEY",
        Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(key),
    }

    err = pem.Encode(outFile, privateKey)
    checkError(err)
}

func savePublicPEMKey2(fileName string, pubkey rsa.PublicKey) {
    //var PublicKeyRow bytes.Buffer

    var pemkey = &pem.Block{
        Type:  "PUBLIC KEY",
        Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PublicKey(&pubkey),
    }

    pemfile, err := os.Create(fileName)
    checkError(err)
    defer pemfile.Close()

    err = pem.Encode(pemfile, pemkey)
    checkError(err)

    //err = pem.Encode(&PublicKeyRow, pemkey)
    //checkError(err)

    //return PublicKeyRow.String()
}

func checkError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Fatal error ", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

the code is working, generate the dkim private/public keys, problem is this keys return bad keys by sender, if i generate keys using this site : https://easydmarc.com/tools/dkim-record-generator/ the keys results valid.

this is my dkim settings in dns :

```
v=DKIM1;t=s;p=MIGJAoGBD1DSPRFFTujiCAiadP9ZeA6eAyf0GktfCQO2WKbrAx2Cu15y2A+agQMWNTmZbbhcznGZiz3kA9y7c0wOqN2iaJchBAxt4qdg1vUhy+6CkSZcY5bdm8uOxsXW3gjOTyZrOur/c118wMTOmSJKHOjn9xLG3ta8tXJtqab8idtx4TlBAgMBAAE=
```

I try to understend what if diferent with my golang key like key generated by easydmarc.com. What i need to change to my golang code for be valid for dkim validation ?